# Is there an easier way to solve big systems of equations?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the system
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
4x^2 - 3xy + 9y^2 = 15,\\
2x + 3y = 5
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Is there any better way than to substitute $\frac{5-2x}{3}$ in for $y$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, we have $$2x+3y=5\tag 1$$
& $$4x^2-3xy+9y^2=15$$
$$4x^2+9y^2+12xy-15xy+9y^2=15$$
$$((2x)^2+2(2x)(3y)+(3y)^2)-15xy=15$$

$$(2x+3y)^2-15xy=15$$
$$(5)^2-15xy=15$$
$$3xy=2$$
$$y=\frac{2}{3x}\tag 2$$
setting value of $y$ from (2) into (1), $$2x+3\cdot\frac{2}{3x}=5$$
$$2x^2-5x+2=0$$
$$(x-2)(2x-1)=0\implies x=2, \frac{1}{2}$$
hence, setting the values of $x$ into (2), one should get corresponding values,
$y=\frac13, \frac 43$
hence, the solution is $\color{red}{x=2, \ y=\frac 13}$ or $\color{blue}{x=\frac 12, \ y=\frac{4}{3}}$

Comment: Should be $(2x+3y)^2-15xy=15$.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I follow where you're going with this. I'm not seeing where you're going from 2 to 3

Comment: Okay I see where you're going with the $(2x + 3y)^2$ but how did you get the $-15xy$?

Comment: We need to add $-15xy$ in LHS to make perfect square $(2x+3y)^2$ because when you expand $(2x+3y)^2$ you will get $4x^2+12xy+9y^2$ which requires to add $-15xy$ to get $$LHS=(2x+3y)^2-15xy=2x^2-3xy+9y^2$$

Answer (score 0):

You also can square the second equation and subtract it from the first equation to get
$$
3xy=2.
$$
On the other hand, also substituting $y=\frac{5-2x}{3}$ immediately gives
$$
2x^2-5x+2=(2x - 1)(x - 2)=0,
$$
which is also fine.

Comment: Ahhh, I see! So that makes it much more managable thank you!